# C# обобщения

Tags: c#

Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
interface ITest<T>
{
}
class a<T> where T : ITest<T>
{
}
class b : ITest<b>
{
}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a<b> A = new a<b>();
    }
}
```

Почему если строчку `class b : ITest<b>`  заменить на `class b : ITest<int>`, то код не компилится. Какая разница int там или b? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вы же сами наложили условие на тип `T`. У вас `T : ITest<T>`.

Для типа `b` условие выполняется, т. к. `b : ITest<b>`. А для `int` — нет.

Если бы вместо `ITest` у вас было `IEquatable`, условие бы сработало, т. к. согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `int : IEquatable<int>` .

Comment: 100 пудов. Сутки мучаю эти обобщения. Спасибо дружище!

Comment: @polyakov_s: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Сорри, спустя год после вопроса вылетело. Я не могу понять, почему для b условие выполняется ? Чем в этом случае b лучше чем int ? Подскажи пожалуйста, а то ступор. Я вижу так, что ITest<T> одинаково не подходят ни один, ни другой.

Comment: @PolyakovSergey: Ну, у вас же в объявлении класса: `class b : ITest<b>`. Значит, `b` подходит под шаблон `T : ITest<T>`. А `int` не имплементирует `ITest<int>` (т. к. `int` вообще ничего про интерфейс `ITest<>` не знает).